# How to hide recaptcha at new page after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I don't need the recaptcha to appear on the new page after the user has submit the form, as it might look unsightly and confusing on the webpage. How can I do that? with **Javascript**.

I don't need to reset the recaptcha as what other solutions show. I just don't want it to appear. Pls help!!

[After form submit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtC9Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only supplied an image of the results of your submission,
I don't know what modifications would be required to your script.

One suggestion might be to save a flag to local storage that would be checked when the page is reloaded after a successful submission.  You might save the date and time and decide if the 'recaptcha' is to be displayed or not based on a sufficient time lapse.  There is also a session storage option, but again without knowledge of your attempts, I don't know if that would satisfy your requirements.  Cookies might be a last option, but some browsers have the ability to inactivate (not save) cookie information which might be critical to your display technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery, you can just hide it using captcha's id or class or it's container's id or class by adding `$('#captcha_id').css('display', 'none')` or using class `$('.captcha_class').css('display', 'none')`

Comment: Thanks for that code but do I have to add 'window.location.reload(true);' because it didn't work.. ?

Comment: No. You don't need to reload that :) Once the page is loaded. That script should run to hide the recaptcha